# How to get same day prior month value using DAX formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

In power BI we need Dax formula which return prior month same day value. Means when report run for 1 April to 8 April 2021, then measure return value of 8 March 2021 only. Can anyone please help me to derive this measures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEADD function paired with CALCULATE like this:

```
PM = 
CALCULATE ( 
    [Total Sales],
    DATEADD ( Dates[Date], -1, MONTH )
)
```

[Previous Month Same Date Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTFfj.png)